# Val, Lynn Chris

Tags: logical-deduction

This is taken from a riddle book:

Val, Lynn and Chris are related to each other, but no incestuously.

1. Among the three are Val's father, Lynn's only daughter, and Chris' sibling.
2. Chris' sibling is neither Val's father nor Lynn's daughter.

Which one is a different sex?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chris is of a different sex to the other two.

---

Lynn is a male, and the father of the other two.

Chris is a female, and Lynn's only daughter.

Val is a male. He's Lynn's son, and Chris's sibling. (He is not his own father, and being male nor is he Lynn's daughter.)